# Indexed Relationships in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm just starting out with using Core Data on the iPhone SDK and I'm looking into saving an ordered list, something like an array. However, relationships in Core Data are expressed as Sets when retrieved. This makes it difficult to save the order in which the objects are positioned.

A good example would be data items in table view when re-ordering of items are allowed. An easy solution would be to include an index property on the managed object.

Consider the following hierarchy:

Document <-Many-to-many-> DataItem

Different Document instances could link to the same DataItem, and each Document might reference one or more DataItem(s). Hence, having an index property in DataItem would lead to less reusability of that instance, i.e. you can only save the index for one instance of Document.

Any ideas of how I can present the hierarchy neatly ordered in a table view but still keep each DataItem instance reusable? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution is to keep a separate data structure in Document to map DataItems to a position in the table view. Besides allowing the same DataItem to exist in multiple positions, if you need to add a DataItem to multiple Documents this solution will also work.

Back when I was looking at different strategies of keeping Core Data objects ordered I found a [blog post](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/comments/per-object_ordered_relationships_using_core_data) that explains how to do this in great detail, including sample code too.

Answer (score 15):

As of OS X Lion (10.7) this is now much more straight forward. Cocoa now has support for a new [NSOrderedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class which is compatible with Core Data. This functionality is also available in iOS though requires iOS 5.0 or later. This means that this can't be used if you want your app to be backwards compatible with earlier versions of iOS or OS X.

All you need to do to gain ordering is open the Core Data model editor, select a to-many relationship and check the "ordered" check-box.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation on this new API? I've only seen it officially discussed in the release notes. I would like to find out, for instance, about displaying records by this order in a Table View

Comment: There's the link in my original answer to NSOrderSet's class reference. However, I don't know of anything specifically pertaining to best use cases within table views.

Comment: `NSOrderedSet` can't currently be used together with iCloud either.

Comment: I must be missing something because I can't find how to specify the sort descriptors for the `NSOrderedSet` you will get when accessing the property. You can of course use a separate fetch request with a sort descriptor, but then what is the point of the ordered property?

Answer (score 7):

You could do it with another entity, like this:
[alt text http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Screenshot-20on-202009-07-04-20at-2010-34-56-20AM/web.jpg?ver=12467253090001](http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Screenshot-20on-202009-07-04-20at-2010-34-56-20AM/web.jpg?ver=12467253090001)

A Document could find its actual dataItems by using something like this:

```
NSSet * documentDataItems = [[document orderedDataItems] valueForKey:@"dataItem"];
```

Likewise, a DataItem could find all its documents by doing the same:

```
NSSet * dataItemDocuments = [[dataItem orderedPositions] valueForKey:@"document"];
```

Comment: @BJ Homer - thanks; Apparently twitpic doesn't like static linking. I uploaded it to MobileMe instead.