# Can i get/set the index generated by checking the 'indexed' checkbox? (core data)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, indexing

I have 2 entities. entity A will hold many entity Bs and order will matter.

if i check the little box that says 'indexed' in xcode, how do i go about using that index, if i even can? ( i know that i CAN use it in some way: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/testing-core-data-with-very-big.html but i am not so spiffy with Obj-c yet.)

I have seen this [Indexed Relationships in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082137/indexed-relationships-in-core-data) , but it seems broken and too much over my head to fix myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index doesn't mean what you think it means.  In this context, "indexed" means like the index of a book.  It add a lookup table so the database can find individual records quickly.  If you need to be able to sort the records into a specific order, use `NSSortDescriptor` with the `NSFetchRequest`.  If the existing properties are not what you want to sort on, you'll need to add another property.

Comment: Thought so, which is why i asked the question. Not the worst thing in the world. Thanks!